# asp.net linq to aadata datatable

Tags: asp.net, ajax, linq, datatable

Hello I have been trying to use dataTable for one project in ASP.net yet I have come into a wall in which I want to pass from sql database to aadata string format, I have managed to get the LINQ query which is the following:

```
     var querytable4 = from table1 in db.ScrapClassifications
                      join table2 in db.ScrapGroups on table1.idGroup equals table2.idGroup
                      join table3 in db.ProdAreas on table1.idArea equals table3.idArea
                      join table4 in db.ScrapSubGroups on table1.idSubGroup equals table4.idSubGroup
                      select new {ActiveBool = table1.Active,
                                   idScrap= table1.idScrapClassification,
                                   Area= table3.Area,
                                   groupDesc= table2.Description,
                                   subgroupdesc=table4.Description,
                                   description=table1.Description
                                    };
```

and it does seem to work correctly displaying all the values, then using Newtonsoft serializer I try to do the following:

```
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(querytable4);
```

and it throws me the following output:

```
  [{\"ActiveBool\":true,\"idScrap\":1,\"Area\":\"Controllers\",\"groupDesc\":...
```

yet my ajaxhandler which is the following:

```
    return Json(new
    {
        sEcho = param.sEcho,
        iTotalRecords = 100,
        iTotalDisplayRecords = 100,
        aaData = json

    },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

only accepts the following format:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult AjaxHandler(jQueryDataTableParamModel param)
    {
        return Json(new{
                sEcho = param.sEcho,
                iTotalRecords = 97,
                iTotalDisplayRecords = 3,
                aaData = new List<string[]>() {
                    new string[] {"1", "Microsoft", "Redmond", "USA"},
                    new string[] {"2", "Google", "Mountain View", "USA"},
                    new string[] {"3", "Gowi", "Pancevo", "Serbia"}
                    }
            },
        JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

anyway to do this conversion? I have been stuck for a week just trying to figure this out, also my database contains booleans and other numeric value, I have also tried to create a list of strings, but when I try to make the conversion it tells me that some values aren't strings in my query..

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by doing the following changes in the query:

```
        var querytable = (from table1 in db.ScrapClassifications
                          join table2 in db.ScrapGroups on table1.idGroup equals table2.idGroup
                          join table3 in db.ProdAreas on table1.idArea equals table3.idArea
                          join table4 in db.ScrapSubGroups on table1.idSubGroup equals table4.idSubGroup
                          select new{Active=table1.Active,
                                       Classification=table1.idScrapClassification,
                                       Area=table3.Area,
                                       Group=table2.Description,
                                       SubGroup=table4.Description,
                                       Description=table1.Description
                                        }).ToArray();
```

then I changed the json input file to the following:

```
        var data = displayquery.Select(d => (new string[] { d.Active.ToString(), d.Classification.ToString(),d.Area.ToString(),d.Group,d.SubGroup,d.Description  }));
```

my Json ended looking like the following:

```
        return Json(new
        {
            sEcho = param.sEcho,
            iTotalRecords = querytable.Count(),
            iTotalDisplayRecords = filteredquery.Count(),
            aaData = data 
        },
       "application/json", Encoding.UTF8, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```